# AJAX callbacks never called, not succes nor error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

// voorkomt de standaard actie van de submit
e.preventDefault();
$(function () {
    var artiest = document.getElementById("artiest");
    var rijen = document.getElementById("rij");
    var kolommen = document.getElementById("kolom");

    var CGIurl = 'http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/schuifpuzzel.py?artiest=' + artiest.value +
        "&rijen=" + rijen.value + "&kolommen=" + kolommen.value  + "&callback=jsonp";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: CGIurl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }

    });

});
});
```

I am trying to run this AJAX to execute my CGI script when the *submit button* is pressed. So I made use of an `eventListener` and `preventDefault`.

The GET seems to be working fine because these are the results I am getting when testing in the browser

[image]

The JSON in the response headers is the one I am trying to retrieve.
But for some reason the succes nor the error in my AJAX is called, so I have no way to access to JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things I can see that are incorrect:

- the JSON response data is sent in the response *headers*, instead of the response *body*;
- jQuery is performing a JSONP request, which means that the response should be valid *Javascript* (not JSON), which should call the supplied callback function (if that doesn't get called, jQuery won't know the request has been completed, hence neither the `success` nor `error` callbacks get called);

Fixing this depends on whether or not you need JSONP. If not, just use `json` as data type and make sure that the JSON data is in the response body. If you do need JSONP, your CGI script should provide a valid JS response, which would look something like this:

```
jQueryXXX({ "content" : { "size" : ... } });
```

(where `jQueryXXX` should be the value of the `callback` query string parameter)

Comment: I am using jsonp because I have read that it was a way to get easily around cors. And I don't get why the data is sent to the response headers I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: @Joey if you need to work around cross-domain boundaries, JSONP is probably what you should use. The reason the data is part of the headers is because there should be an empty line between the headers and the body data. It depends on your server implementation how to achieve this, but it can be as simple as prefixing the JS string with a newline.

Comment: Ok, so one problem fixed the response now shows the json. I am getting an `uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ":"` now. And still the succes/error is never called. Probably because of the syntax error?

Comment: Yes. You are probably sending back a JSON string, not a valid JS response that calls the callback function (see my answer).